# Suppose $X$ has density $f$ and $Y$ has density $g$. Is it possible $f(x)>g(x)$ for all $x$?

Tags: statistics

> Suppose $X$ has density $f$ and $Y$ has density $g$. Is it possible $f(x)>g(x)$ for all $x$?

I'm assuming won't be the case because then $\int f(t)dt>\int g(t)dt$? But I'm not sure if this is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. you are right. As $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x) dx = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}g(x) dx = 1$, and if $f(x) > g(x)$ for all $x$ means $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x) dx > \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}g(x)$, it is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely: if you integrate functions on any segment [a, b] both integrals will be defined and integral of f - g will be positive. Therefore full integral of f - g will be positive, so integrals of f and g cannot be the same